# Chrome re-directs to spam site

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, malware

This might be a little unrelated to this stack but I could not find a more suitable place. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and have chrome installed on it. The problem is when I try to access a particular website it re-directs me to some spam site. But when I open chrome in incognito it takes me to the correct site. What is gong on here and how to fix it?

Comment: Like Ananda Kharisma, I would suspect add-ons because they are deactivated in an incognito session. It is also possible that the server redirects you based on cookies or other data that is present in your session only. You could try deleting cookies and cache for that website. Can you tell us the particular website? Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: @danzel shouldn't add-ons affect all website I have a lot of experience on net and I can assure you this is not a particular famous spam website but randomly directing to some spam sites

Comment: that depends on the developer's intention. If the add-on spammed every site right from the start, you would uninstall it. But if you notice spam redirects months later and only on specific sites, you won't necessarily suspect the add-on. Did you try with all add-ons disabled?

Comment: @danzel consciously I have enabled no add-ons and in all my experience I never have...This is something totally new...I cannot figure it on why trying to access a specific site redirects me

Comment: @danzel http://ww2.ww2.ww92.ww92.ww92.ww92.ww62.ww62.ww62.ww62.ww62.ww2.acessoriosparablogs.com.br/  this site is a recurrence

Comment: I wanted to know the site you are actually trying to access, not the spam site.

Comment: @danzel oh it's my college website...

Comment: Try [clearing Chrome's DNS cache](https://superuser.com/a/203702/398021).

Comment: did this solve your problem?

Comment: @danzel nopes, I am not sure i want to do any online transaction from my laptop now